# Set production URL Jhipster

Tags: jhipster

When I package for production, and I want to recover my password, url which leads me to my mail it is incorrect.

```
http://localhost:8095/af/#/reset/finish?key=03106204321257101265
```

The right thing would be

```
https://www.XXX.es/af/#/reset/finish?key=03106204321257101265
```

I do not see any property in .yml and not to the steps to put the base url me I need.

Jhipster 3.4.2

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

Set `server.port` and `server.address` properties in your `application-prod.yml` file. Please refer to [Spring Boot doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html) for details and alternate ways of setting these.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that dynamically form, but when it is on the server also takes as "request.getServerName()"= "localhost"

Do not use the built-in Jhipster Tomcat, but other external.

```
 public ResponseEntity<?> requestPasswordReset(@RequestBody String mail, HttpServletRequest request) {
    System.out.println("scheme"+ request.getScheme());
    System.out.println("server name" + request.getServerName());
    System.out.println("server port" + request.getServerPort());
    System.out.println("context path"+ request.getContextPath());

    return userService.requestPasswordReset(mail)
        .map(user -> {
            String baseUrl = request.getScheme() +
                "://" +
                request.getServerName() +
                ":" +
                request.getServerPort() +
                request.getContextPath();
            mailService.sendPasswordResetMail(user, baseUrl);
            return new ResponseEntity<>("e-mail was sent", HttpStatus.OK);
        }).orElse(new ResponseEntity<>("e-mail address not registered", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST));
}
```